# Can't connect Java program to Access 2010 Database Using ODBC Driver

Tags: java, ms-access, odbc

So I have spent 48 hours on this and I cant get it right!

I am writing Java using 64-bit BlueJ program.
I am using 64-bit MS Windows 7
I am trying to connect to MS Access 2010 (x86/x64)

The following shows my code to make a connection:

```
 /** 
         * Makes connection to FIREPLACES Database.
         * 
         * @return 0 if connection to FIREPLACES database is successfully made, 
         *           otherwise returns -1 if there is a problem making a connection 
         *           to the BOOKS database.
         * 
        */
        static public int makeConnectionToFireplacesDB()
          {

              try
                {
                        // Make connection to Database
                        connectionToFireplacesDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:FIREPLACES");
                }
              catch (SQLException exception)
                {       
                        return (-1);    // Return back with -1 if there is a problem 
                                        // making a connection
                }

              return (0);   // Return back with 0 if connection is made to database

          } // end makeConnectionToBooksDB()
```

The name of the access file that I am connecting to is called FIREPLACES.mdb.

After having trouble and trauling the interweb for a solution I discovered that I needed to create the connection using the odbc driver through windows/SysWOW64/odbcad32.exe.

I did this but it still gave me the same problem!

I felt it must be a x86/x64 so I installed x86 operating system on a different hard drive but still, the same problem!

The screenshot below shows me trying to create the connection on the odbc driver:

[image: trying to use odbc driver]

I really cant think of any more information I can provide.

Any help really would be magnificent! I am stuck in a major rut from this...

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that your method returns -1? If so, it would be helpful to actually print the Exception instead of ignoring it (insert `exception.printStackTrace();` before `return -1;`. It will give you some information about why the connection failed.

Comment: @assylias do I do this by returning exception.getErrorCode() instead of -1? I am on very new ground here

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use 64-bit Java ODBC driver with a Access database on Windows 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381504/how-do-i-use-64-bit-java-odbc-driver-with-a-access-database-on-windows-2008)

Comment: There is no ODBC bridge driver for 64-bit Java.  You're out of luck.

Comment: @duffymo even with JDK 64 bits / Access 64 bits?

Comment: Right, if I recall correctly there is no ODBC bridge driver in the 64 bit JDK.  You need a DLL that isn't included.

Comment: @duffymo I know that it it is defo possible but unfortunately that is far as I can get.,.. which doesn't help me. I have spoken to a few colleagues who have it working on their systems but they are unable to help.

Comment: If they have it 'working', you ought to be studying their systems to see how they differ from yours.

Comment: I know but they are unavailable. I am all on my own!

Comment: @assylias I have done what you said but I am met with 3 or 400 lines of errors.. how do I disect this?

Comment: @Phil the first few lines are generally more interesting - the rest drills down into the libraries which you would (generally) not really care about.

Comment: @assylias so here are the first few! 

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at DataBaseHandler.searchAllFireplaces(DataBaseHandler.java:220)
 at ReportingScreen.displayAllFireplaces(ReportingScreen.java:273)
 at ReportingScreen.<init>(ReportingScreen.java:61)
 at MainMenuScreen.actionPerformed(MainMenuScreen.java:328)

Comment: @assylias not sure what to do with this

Comment: @Phil this is an exception thrown from the GUI thread. So you must have a gui component somewhere that relies on getting a connection and throws that because the connection is null (just a guess). I would advise you create a short [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that only involves connecting to the database and retrieving one record for example. By eliminating unrelated code you should understand better what fails.

Comment: @Phil Also check [the code at the bottom of this page](http://www.selikoff.net/2011/07/26/connecting-to-ms-access-file-via-jdbc-in-64-bit-java/). Not sure if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question, well for me, the answer was simple, whack 32-bit onto a partition and try again... Worked fine then!